# Android : how to get jsonarray from json object in different ways

Tags: android, json, for-loop

I know  how to get `jsonarray` from `jsonobject`. I am doing like below code to get jsonarray.

```
JSONObject recvJson = new JSONObject(holder.toString());   
String numberByte= (String) recvJson.get("data");
String ts = (String) recvJson.get("time");
JSONObject temp2 = new JSONObject("{ \"data\" : " + numberByte+ "}");
JSONArray recvJarray = temp2.getJSONArray("data"); 

for (int i = 0; i < recvJarray.length(); i++) 
{
byteArray[i] = (byte) recvJarray.getInt(i); 
}
```

But don't want to use `for-loop`, without using **for-loop** or **any other loop** want to **retrieve jsonarray data values**.

How should I do ?? I have done google & saw many forums but dint succeed to retrieve data without using for-loop.

**for example :** `I ll be getting 80 - 100 packets of 1024bytes per second from server, I want to retrieve this data & store it into bytearray`. By usingf for-loop its taking around 300ms- 400ms and I am loosing many packets between that. So I want to use different approach. If any Idea or solution for cracking this.

Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: jsonArray is array. So if you want to get values from array you've got to iterate over array. If you don't like `for` operator you can use `while` construction.

Comment: it ll take some time to retrieve data array from loop. any other way of using without loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GSON to parse the json objects. It is much faster and easier to decode json data.
Check these links. 
[Gson1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-gson-to-work-with-json-in-your-android-apps/1386), [Gson2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

try usig [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

it uses java reflection to convert objects to json and json to object with simple methods

toJson(),fromJson() (and it works for object arrays and lists  too)

but you have to write the proper classes for the jsons (with all fields)

read the documentation.

Comment: i am not sure. gson may use loops implicitly. but this way you dont have to use any loop. you can get list<YourObject> with only one method call.But json array... may be you can achieve by reursion. but i dont recommend

Comment: I cant use Recursion .. It ll take more time then looping I think.. I ll be getting 80 - 100 packets of 1024bytes per second.